# Lenovo 14w 2 touchpad doesn't work with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, lenovo

Using a brand new Lenovo 14W Gen2 I can't get the touchpad to work using ubuntu 18.04, me and my collegues have tried many things from using the live bootable to compiling the kernel from scratch and we cannot get the touch pad to work, this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1952411) refers to a page submitted to cannonical for support by one of my collegues aswell and contains reports.

Some of the tests done are found from these sources [A](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1952411), [B](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277), [C](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277), [D](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277), [E](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277), [F](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04/)
We have tried a lot of things already that have not worked, we have even asked lenovo for support without success, I could not post all the links to the tests we have done

Comment: Are there any updates on this issue?

Comment: A BIOS update seemed to do the trick